# BulkExecution in Azure CosmosDB for ASP.Net MVC 4.7.2 version

Tags: asp.net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

***Description:***
What's my goal : want to do bulk execution for Vertices and edges to create graph in azure cosmosDB with c# code as below

```cs
BulkOperationResponse bulkOperationResponse1 =await graphBulkExecutor.BulkImportAsync( gremlinElements: gremlinElements1, enableUpsert: true);
```

Source : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-graph-bulk-executor

***Result:*** This approach working very well with `.NET Core MVC` application but not with `ASP.NET Framework MVC` app.

***Issue area:*** After debugging I found the exception line is at

```cs
 await this.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken);"
```

and this is from

[image]

Comment: Please share the exception details (stack trace, ToString()), the image shows a NullReferenceException, you need to first investigate where the null reference comes from to understand which code is the problem.